# Asymmetric confidence intervals for Cohen's kappa

Tags: confidence-interval, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

I am trying to understand sample sizes required to estimate Cohen's k with a given precision. I am aware that the traditional confidence intervals do not achieve the nominal coverage in small samples, though I am confused by the wide range of findings regarding that. More importantly, however, I am struggling to find an approach that accounts for the asymetry inherent in a correlation coefficient.

When I bootstrap confidence intervals for Cohen's kappa, they are (obviously) not symmetric but bounded at 1 and/or right-skewed. For Pearson's r, the way to account for that would be to transform it to z-scores, create the confidence interval, and transform it back. Is something similar possible and/or appropriate for Cohen's kappa? It would seem necessary, but I have not yet seen anything in that direction.

Comment: Is the basic issue that you are bothered by the fact that the confidence interval is not symmetrical ?

Comment: The main issue is that the analytic confidence intervals (based on standard errors) show extreme undercoverage ... and I am wondering whether that is because they should be asymmetric ...